# jQuery UI: How to check whether another instance of widget is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu, jquery-ui-menu

I've created custom widget by extending jQuery UI's [Menu](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/). It's basically needed to work with `<select>` HTML element like [ui.selectmenu](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu) does, but display options in submenus:

```
$.widget("market.myMenu",$.ui.menu, {
// ...
_attachEvents: function(){
    var self = this;
    // menu is initially hidden
    self.menuWrapper.hide();
    self.button.on('click', function(){
        if (self.originalSelect.is(':disabled')) {
            self.disable();
        } else {                
            self.menuWrapper.toggle();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(){
        self.menuWrapper.hide();
    });             
},
//...
  }
}
```

The problem arise when this widget attached to multiple elements like:

```
someSelect.myMenu();
//...
anotherSelect.myMenu();
```

The problem is listed in the title and you can see it in `_attachEvents()` method:

1. when user clicks on `someSelect` it opens as should
2. then user clicks on `anotherSelect` it also opens
3. `someSelect` after step `2` should be closed, but it's not.

So how to check for such a case and fix this issue ?

EDIT:

1. `this.originalSelect` is `<select>` HTML element
2. `this.button` is div element. on which selected option text is displayed (basically same thing as `ui.selectmenu` does);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class to keep track of the state of your menus and use it to target instances that are opened. Something like this for example:

```
_attachEvents: function(){
    var self = this;
    // menu is initially hidden
    self.menuWrapper.hide();
    self.button.on('click', function(){
        if (self.originalSelect.is(':disabled')) {
            self.disable();
        } else {
            // before you open a menu, you close the opened ones
            $('menu-opened').each(function(){
                $(this).myMenu('instance').hideWrapper();
            });
            self.menuWrapper.toggleClass('menu-opened');                
            self.menuWrapper.toggle();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(){
        self.menuWrapper.hide();
    });             
},

hideWrapper: function(){
    var self = this;
    self.menuWrapper.hide();
    self.menuWrapper.removeClass('menu-opened');
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, and it doesn't work as should. The `instance` method silently fails, also would you please fix a typo on selector `.menu-opened`. But anyway I took your idea about marking wrapper with some css class, that is why I accept your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. It's based upon **Julien Grégoire** proposal to use css marker class.

What I'm doing is adding class `ui-mymenu-wrap` to `self.menuWrapper` element. So all widgets have those identifier. The next thing I do is after clicking on one widget I'm closing all others menus and then open/close widget on which click was made.

```
_attachEvents: function(){
    var self = this;
    // menu is initially hidden
    self.menuWrapper.hide();
    self.button.on('click', function(event){
        if (self.originalSelect.is(':disabled')) {
            self.disable();
        } else {
            // hide all opened menus
            $('.ui-mymenu-wrap').not(self.menuWrapper).hide();
            self.menuWrapper.toggle();                  
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(){
        self.menuWrapper.hide();
    });             
},
```